# Difference between Armour levels?

Tags: pubg-battlegrounds

There are three levels of armour in the game, I am wondering how much difference there is between level 1, 2 and 3?

Is there like a spreadsheet somewhere showing this for each different piece of armour?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Level 1 absorbs 30% of incoming damage, level 2 absorbs 40%, level 3 absorbs 55%.

This spreadsheet contains a breakdown of the damage in the game whether it be how much damage a particular gun does or how much damage it does to a certain piece of armor and the damage mitigation for each piece in general:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13ZI5GQDbCXl7IlVCVnEA6aZVfC7NFJLBsXPIAGFMNj4/edit#gid=1777964351

I would also recommend heading over to the PUBG subreddit (r/pubattlegrounds) for a lot of other helpful info

Comment: Since links can die, could you at least explain what the document contains? Link-only answers are discouraged because at any point in the future, the link may no longer work or not go to the same page it was intended to.

Comment: @OrcJMR Much better post edit, thanks for taking the time to improve the answer.