# Is Damage taken impacted by durability of a piece of armor?

Tags: pubg-battlegrounds

[I have seen this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/315461/difference-between-armour-levels) and [this spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13ZI5GQDbCXl7IlVCVnEA6aZVfC7NFJLBsXPIAGFMNj4/edit#gid=861361693), but I am looking for clarification.

I want to know if a heavily damaged, higher level piece of armor will offer more protection than a lower level piece of armor with no damage to it.

Example: If I have a level 3 helmet with 1 durability (heavily damaged), will it still absorb 55% of damage and thus making it better than a level 2 helmet with 150 durability ?

I frequently swap out my armor for the least damaged item, but [from this video (just found today), it is making me rethink it.](https://youtu.be/xMbFEOdG9Vc?t=7m4s)

Comment: [The wiki](https://pubg.gamepedia.com/Vests) says "Body armor will last until fully destroyed by gunfire or other types of damage and will block the full damage **even if it has only 1 point of armor left**."  How credible it is, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Armour and Helmets will reduce damage done by the same amount regardless of how much durability it has.**

I suspect this may be because when you are hit reduced damage is applied to the player, followed by durability being subtracted from the armour/helmet. Regardless, a armour/helmet of any level will protect you the same amount whether it has 1 point of durability or full durability.

When it comes to deciding whether or not to switch out for lower level but higher durability gear, you need to consider how many times you are likely to be shot. A full durability lvl 2 vest will prevent more damage than a lvl 3 vest with 10 durability **if you are shot more than once.**

You can find more about the mechanics of armour and helmets in this video:

Even though the video is from April, there isn't evidence that they have changed the mechanic in the recent patches.

Answer (score 0):

The durability of the item is not related to how much damage it will absorb, it is essentially just how much more damage you can take before it breaks.

A headshot with 1 durability vs 150 will not change the damage, therefor it is mostly better to take a higher tier item with a lower durability than a lower tier item with higher durability (there are some cases where you would want to keep the lower tier as if it breaks you have nothing).

I always exchange higher tiers regardless of durability.

Comment: Can you provide a source for this info?

Comment: @Exerion I googled it a bit and found some reddit/steam community posts saying that the amount of damage it reduces does not reduce with the durability. [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/PUBATTLEGROUNDS/comments/6frakb/should_i_replace_damaged_lvl_3_armor_and_helmets/) and [SteamComm](https://steamcommunity.com/app/578080/discussions/1/135513549099027059/).